# Drawing conductometric curve in tikz

Tags: tikz-styles

I would like to draw conductivity graph using tikz, so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\draw[<->](0,5)|-(5,0);% drawing axes
\draw(0,2)..controls(1.5,.5)..(3.2,4)--(4.6,4.1);
\end{document}
```

Giving me the image below
[image]
The required graph is this one below
[image: see]
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea here is rather using `rounded corners` than a Bezier curve.

[image: conductometry]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[->](0,0)--(5,0) node [below left] {Volume of NaOH};
        \draw[->](0,0)-- node [sloped,at end,above left] {Conductivity} (0,5) ;
        \draw[rounded corners](0,2) node[left]{A} -- (1,1)node[below]{B}  -- (3.2,4) node[above left]{C} --(4.6,4) node[above]{D};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: If you want to round only point B, just separate the drawing into two different parts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[->](0,0)--(5,0) node [below left] {Volume of NaOH};
        \draw[->](0,0)-- node [sloped,at end,above left] {Conductivity} (0,5) ;
        \draw[rounded corners](0,2) node[left]{A} -- (1,1)node[below]{B}  -- (3.2,4) node[above left]{C};
        \draw (3.2,4) --(4.6,4) node[above]{D};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: second version]

Comment: is it possible to have only point B rounded?

Comment: Yes but it's not what your picture shows. I'll edit my answer accordingly.